# Configure NGINX on Centos 6.8

Tags: 7

I have nginx installed on our server and configured with a previous drupal 7 installation and it works well.

I have installed a new drupal 7 installation and i want to configure it to also work with NGINX already installed on the server. Is there a configuration file i have to update? Please someone point me to the right direction.

This new site is running on the same server but a different cpanel with the previous site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new Server Block for the new domain.

This is the file that NGINX reads in order to determine where it will look for the site when a request for a domain come through.

The configuration will be under

```
/etc/nginx
```

The relevant/current entry could be in `nginx.conf`, in a file under `conf.d` or `sites-available`.

Comment: By server block, you mean like cpanel? i checked in /etc/nginx/vhosts and i see 2 files with the names of the domains in there. the contents of the files are similar for both domains, however, one of the sites runs pretty much faster than the other which is its replica. do i have to do a manual configuration in settings.php or .http file to make the other site use nginx? could i be doing something wrong

Comment: I have no idea about Cpanel, but once you can access the site, it means the configuration for nginx is done. The only thing you need to do in the `settings.php` is make sure you are pointing to the right database with the right credentials. You don't want both sites to share the database.